# Serilog outputTemplate for Microsoft.Extensions.Logging Category

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, serilog

[Samples in aspnet core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging) have logger category in output (`TodoApi.Controllers.TodoController`). Which Serilog's `outputTemplate` use have same output? None of `{Logger}{Category}{EventId}` works.

Answer (score 3):

`{SourceContext}` its name (https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging/issues/9).